# list of custom object does not sort descending

Tags: c#

I have the following class

```
public class Person
{
    public string MottagarNamn { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int StreetNummer { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public int IntExtraInfoToSortBy { get; set; }
}
```

I populate it like this..

```
 userList.Add(new Person() { MottagarNamn = "John Doe", City = "Orlando", Street = "Main Street apt 13", StreetNummer = 42, PostalCode = "111 22", IntExtraInfoToSortBy = 13 });
 userList.Add(new Person() { MottagarNamn = "John Doe", City = "Orlando", Street = "Main Street apt 17", StreetNummer = 42, PostalCode = "111 22", IntExtraInfoToSortBy = 17 });
 userList.Add(new Person() { MottagarNamn = "John Doe", City = "Orlando", Street = "Main Street apt 4", StreetNummer = 42, PostalCode = "111 22", IntExtraInfoToSortBy = 4 });
 userList.Add(new Person() { MottagarNamn = "John Doe", City = "Orlando", Street = "Main Street apt", StreetNummer = 42, PostalCode = "111 22", IntExtraInfoToSortBy = 0 });
```

When I try to sort the list desc by ExtraInfoToSortBy it does not order it descending, why is that?

```
userList = userList.OrderByDescending(x => x.ExtraInfoToSortBy).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you expect when you write "does not order it descending"? I tried the code and it sorts the list descending. I see items in this order -> 17, 13, 4, 0

Comment: Please share a [mcve] **that compiles**.

Comment: Also, this extra info seems like number of a building/parcel on particular street...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should throw error instead of not descending as your lambda is using property "**ExtraInfoToSortBy**" which is not in Person class.

Instead of that use '**IntExtraInfoToSortBy**"

```
userList = userList.OrderByDescending(x => x.IntExtraInfoToSortBy).ToList();
```

Let me know if still you are getting issue.

Comment: Yes, and in fact this sorts quite fine.

Comment: Sorry, before I posted the question I removed parts that was unnecessary and while doing that I also made a mistake to not sort by "IntExtraInfoToSortBy" as Amit Verma noticed, it now works as expected. Thanks